# layoutIfNeeded happens after a noticeable delay

Tags: cocoa-touch, autolayout, uikit, uianimation

After changing the constraints on some of my view components, I'm calling `layoutIfNeeded` to perform the changes. The problem is that sometimes there's a very evident delay between the method call and the actual visual change. What am I doing wrong?

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Answer (score 1):

I just realised you're supposed to call `layoutIfNeeded` while on the main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.loginFormConstraintX.constant = -1024;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
});
```